# How to work with Github Actions without .env file

Tags: laravel, github, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, github-actions

I'm trying to perform deploy Laravel app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk with Github Actions but I had questions on running Github actions because currently I'm try to avoid upload `.env` file to my repository.

Below provided the default workflows which generated by Github

```
name: Laravel

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  laravel-tests:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: shivammathur/setup-php@15c43e89cdef867065b0213be354c2841860869e
      with:
        php-version: '8.0'
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Copy .env
      run: php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: composer install -q --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-scripts --no-progress --prefer-dist
    - name: Generate key
      run: php artisan key:generate
    - name: Directory Permissions
      run: chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache
    - name: Create Database
      run: |
        mkdir -p database
        touch database/database.sqlite
    - name: Execute tests (Unit and Feature tests) via PHPUnit
      env:
        DB_CONNECTION: sqlite
        DB_DATABASE: database/database.sqlite
      run: vendor/bin/phpunit
```

The generated file showing error

```
There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Feature\ExampleTest::test_the_application_returns_a_successful_response
Expected response status code [200] but received 500.
Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 500.

The following exception occurred during the last request:

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: users in /home/runner/work/sampleSearch/sampleSearch/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:414
```

So may I know how can I solve this connection issues without upload `.env` file?

Comment: I' don't know if it helpful but when I encounter this problem I just add `use RefreshDatabase` trait to my test. Maybe because there is no tables inside the database.sqlite.

Comment: @xenooooo yes it works, I thought is my env file didn't uploaded cause the problems